# interface key as string constant

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In typescript, we can define an Object type using an interface and by using the specific key we can access the value of an object.

Is their any way in typescript through which we can declare a type and use the same type as a constant string.

e.g.

```
interface dummyObject{
    key1: string;
}

let obj: dummyObject;

obj[dummyObject.key1] = "4";
[ts]'dummyObject' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Any Help is Appreciated.

Regards

Ajay

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but I totally do not understand this question.

Comment: @RoyDictus Thanks for replying. To define the type of an object we declare an interface. Can we use the interface key to access the object property? If not, Is there any other way in typescript to implement this functionality?  Declaring the structure for an object and using the same structure when accessing the object properties in typescript.